# Running more than one instance of Evince

Tags: linux, multiple-instances

I have a wxPython application and I'm using Evince to display the reports it generates.
Since I'd like to delete every report after the user has closed the corresponding Evince instance, my application uses a  thread that does a subprocess.call() to invoke Evince, and then removes the report when the subprocess terminates.
This works fine as long as the user looks at just one report at a time, because if he opens one report and then another (without closing the previous one) the previous Evince instance gets "recycled" to show the new report, so subprocess.call() returns immediately and the file gets deleted too soon.
Is there a way to force Evince to use a new instance every time?

(Xubuntu 8.10)

Comment: This is a rather specialized area of questioning.  You just might want to contact the Evince developers themselves.
http://live.gnome.org/Evince/Contact

Comment: Yes I agree, I posted on that ML too.. I was hoping that the "Stack overflow effect" would come up with an answer in a matter of minutes as usual :D Thanks for your hint anyway!

Comment: it also happens if you have one evince open and double click the same file. i'm trying to open two instances of a wiring diagram to compare data from 2 pages. but the gnome developers in all their wisdom decided to make one app behave differently from all the others. will have to take screen shots of the pages to compare them side-by-side... geez

Comment: @gcb someone called them "interface nazis" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouter Bolsterlee [suggests](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2009-April/msg00018.html):

> dbus-launch --exit-with-session evince
>   file://...

Comment: I just found out that this way the process keeps running even when you close evince.. :/ (Tried with Ubuntu 9.04 and 8.10)
I ended up using epdfview instead of evince, works nicely and with fewer problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with evince. 
Try suggesting that to the developers as a new feature.

Comment: Someone tried that already, but they told him it was against the design principles of Gnome :/
http://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2009-April/msg00019.html

Comment: That's one of the reasons I prefer KDE - the Gnome people care more about their design principles than their users

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version that comes with Ubuntu Lucid (2.30) **does** work for my usecase... Maybe they changed their mind :)